# Expandable recycler view and a textview below issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to implement a 2 expandable recyclerview with 2 headings.So my view has 
1. 
2. 
3. 
4. 
Since my recyclerview is expandable, and when I expand the 1st recyclerview , it goes inside my 2nd textview.
ie.there is a separate scroll for my recycler view.

I want the 2nd textview and recyclerview to move down when expanding the 1st recyclerview.

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    tools:context=".ListActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="Weightage: 40%"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fafafa" />
</LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Weightage: 60%"/>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recview2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fafafa" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

the same happens with the second recyclerview. On expanding the second recycler view, recyclerview items have a separate scroll and the text above stays at a place.The overall scroll doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using only one Recyclerview. Make one model class named "Model" of your data, in which add one variable like "isHeader". When you prepare your data list to show in Recyclerview make 2 model object with 
'isHeader = true'

Also, make two (item_layout.xml & header_layout.xml) xml files, one for header & another for your original data item.

And in Recyclerview adapter class you have two separate ViewHolder classes for each of the above layouts. [refer this for more details and example](https://www.journaldev.com/12372/android-recyclerview-example)

```html
public class MultiViewTypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    public static final int HEADER_VIEW = 0;
    public static final int LIST_VIEW = 1;

    private Resources resources;
    private DownloadListener downloadListener;

    public MyToursAdapter(List<Model> objects) {
        super(objects);
        resources = App.getApp().getResources();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecycleView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        if (viewType == HEADER_VIEW) {
            return new SectionHeaderItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.header_layout, parent, false));
        } else
            return new ListItemViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull BaseRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == HEADER_VIEW)
            ((HeaderItemViewHolder) holder).bindHeaderViewHolder(objects.get(position));
        else
            ((ListItemViewHolder) holder).bindListViewHolder(objects.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (objects.get(position).isHeader())
            return HEADER_VIEW;
        else
            return LIST_VIEW;
    }

  public class ListItemViewHolder extends BaseRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder {
     //write code to show data from list object.
  }

  public class HeaderItemViewHolder extends BaseRecycleAdapter.ViewHolder {
     //write code to show data from list object.
  }
}
```

`enter code here`